# Apresentação do gráfico na página

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Tenho este gráfico com a seguinte query à base de dados:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Ano','Janeiro', 'Fevereiro','Marco', 'Abril','Maio', 'Junho','Julho', 'Agosto','Setembro', 'Outubro','Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
          <?php 
                   $query = "SELECT `B`.`DescricaoProd`,
       YEAR(`A`.`Data`) AS `Ano`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 1 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Janeiro`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 2 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Fevereiro`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 3 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Marco`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 4 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Abril`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 5 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Maio`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 6 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Junho`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 7 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Julho`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 8 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Agosto`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 9 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Setembro`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 10 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Outubro`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 11 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Novembro`,
       CAST(SUM(IF(MONTH(`A`.`Data`) = 12 , `A`.`Quantidade`, 0)) AS DECIMAL (15 , 0 )) AS `Dezembro`

FROM(
SELECT `centrodb`.`regSaidahigieneAntigo`.`Produto`,        
       `centrodb`.`regSaidahigieneAntigo`.`DataAtribuicao` AS `Data`,
       `centrodb`.`regSaidahigieneAntigo`.`Quantidade`

FROM `centrodb`.`regSaidahigieneAntigo`

UNION ALL

SELECT `A`.`Produto`,        
       `A`.`DataAtribuicao` AS `Data`,
       `A`.`Quantidade`

FROM `centrodb`.`regSaidahigiene` AS `A` 

UNION ALL

SELECT `centrodb`.`RegSaidaLuvas`.`Produto`,
       `centrodb`.`RegSaidaLuvas`.`DataSaida`,
       `centrodb`.`RegSaidaLuvas`.`QtaHigiene`


 FROM `centrodb`.`RegSaidaLuvas`

 WHERE `centrodb`.`RegSaidaLuvas`.`Produto` IS NOT NULL) AS `A` LEFT OUTER JOIN `centrodb`.`ProdHigiene` AS `B`
ON `B`.`IDProd` = `A`.`Produto`

WHERE YEAR(`A`.`Data`) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 YEAR)
      OR
      YEAR(`A`.`Data`) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

GROUP BY `B`.`DescricaoProd`,  `Ano`

ORDER BY `B`.`DescricaoProd`, YEAR(`A`.`Data`)";    
                   $exec = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){    
                      echo "['".$row['Ano']."',".$row['Janeiro'].",".$row['Fevereiro'].",".$row['Marco'].",".$row['Abril'].",".$row['Maio'].",".$row['Junho'].",".$row['Julho'].",".$row['Agosto'].",".$row['Setembro'].",".$row['Outubro'].",".$row['Novembro'].",".$row['Dezembro']."],";
                   }
                ?>     
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 2000px; height: 1000px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Está tudo a funcionar correto com o código, não estou a conseguir é apresentar os dados como pretendo. Nas imagens mostro como me aparecem os resultados no gráfico de duas formas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira imagem aparece o ano e o mês mas não aprece o nome do produto a que se refere aquela quantidade.
Na segunda imagem aparece o produto e o mês, mas não aparece o ano a que se refere, uma vez que mostro o resultado do ano atual e do ano anterior.

O que pretendo mostrar no gráfico é o nome do produto, o total gasto por mês e a que ano e mês pertence aquele total.

Comment: Vc usou o Google charts? Ou outra api de graficos?

Comment: Usei google charts

Comment: Me passa o link do grafico q vc usou

Comment: [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

Comment: Sugere que utilize outro gráfico do google charts?

Comment: Se o jeito que sugeri não atende, acho melhor usar outro grafico msm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aonde você nomeia as colunas, acho que fica melhor com o nome dos produtos

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['DescricaoProd','Janeiro', 'Fevereiro','Marco', 'Abril','Maio', 'Junho','Julho', 'Agosto','Setembro', 'Outubro','Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
```

E no loop onde você imprime, não consegui fazer com que fosse possivel "Pular linha" então coloquei o ano do lado, não sei se te atende da forma ideal.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){    
                      echo "['".$row['DescricaoProd']." - ".$row['Ano']."',".$row['Janeiro'].",".$row['Fevereiro'].",".$row['Marco'].",".$row['Abril'].",".$row['Maio'].",".$row['Junho'].",".$row['Julho'].",".$row['Agosto'].",".$row['Setembro'].",".$row['Outubro'].",".$row['Novembro'].",".$row['Dezembro']."],";
                   }
```

Se isso não te atende e você quer a informação de forma "independente", ai sugiro que vc utilize outro grafico

**Resp:** Um exemplo de filtro, seria fazer o usuario antes de acessar o gráfico, escolher um produto, como o Álcool, ele vai pra uma variável `($produto)`, e quando seu gráfico for carregado, o Select saia desse jeito:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM BANCOX.TABELAX WHERE DescricaoProd = '$produto'";
```

Só um exemplo generico :D

Comment: Sim, é isso que pretendo, só tenho outro problema, as barras ficam muito finas, queria que ficassem mais grossas de forma a ser mais fácil a análise

Comment: Está saindo pequeno assim devido a quantidade de barras
Se você colcocar um filtro de um um produto exibido por vez, fica melhor a exibição do msm
Ou dividir os produtos por graficos nesta pagina, mas ai já é gambiarra dms kkk

Comment: e como posso colocar um filtro por produto, pode colocar um exemplo?

Comment: Editei a resposta com um exemplo

Comment: E não é possível o usuário escolher mais do que 1 produto? por exemplo 3 produtos?

Comment: é possível sim, mas isso depende do seu objetivo é só mostrar os dados, acho que um dado por vez é o suficiente, agora se for com o objetivo de comparação, depende de quantos vc quer comparar, se for 2 ou mais, ai depende de vc fazer a quantidade de inputs necessario

Comment: Na parte da edição da pergunta sobre o filtro, não chega o que colocou. Não estou a conseguir criar o filtro só com o seu exemplo

Comment: Vc tem que adapta-lo a sua query, e se necessário criar uma pagina extra, se mesmo assim estiver tendo dificuldade, recomendo que crie outra pergunta com maiores informações do que vc deseja e outros usuários poderão te ajudar

Comment: Mas em relação ao exemplo que colocaste para filtrar por produto no gráfico podes só colocar o exemplo completo, porque não basta colocar a variável no `where`